# Calculate cumulative distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have on the datebase a table containing:

- created_at
- order_id
- customer_id

I want to calculate the cumulative distinct number of customers per day.

I wrote this query

```
SELECT
    created_at::date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) OVER (ORDER BY created_at::date) as cumulative_users
FROM orders
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

then I figured out that PostgreSQL doesn't support distinct in a window function.

Can you please help me writing this code?

Comment: Always add some example with a desired outcome because it is not easy to get your idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH firstseen AS (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        MIN(created_at) created_at
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT created_at :: date,
    COUNT(customer_id) OVER (ORDER BY created_at :: date) daily_cumulative_count
FROM firstseen
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

No windowing function needed here imho.

```
select created_at , count(distinct customer_id) from order_table group by created_at;
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/94bc2f/1)

Comment: I want to calculate the cumulative number of users day over day, not an aggregation per day.
Thanks for your reply

Comment: Not sure I get you right because your own try - despite if it works or not - groups it by date..... maybe you provide sample data and expected result...

SELECT SUM(num) FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS num FROM order_table GROUP BY created_at) AS a;

Comment: Thanks @Olli for your will to help, I just found the right query.
I shared it in the next comment

Comment: well OK, but thats not cumulative count as it would need to accumulate every previous number of (distinct) customers of each previous date to be accumulative :) Maybe check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a5c4d/18

Comment: Hello @Olli, I checked out your query, the output should be: 2, 3, 3 instead of 2, 5, 7